# is there a way i can change the color of the arrow in the appBar after using pushNamed?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-appbar

The reason is cause the background color of my new page is 'white' and so is the arrow so it is not visible.

Answer (score 2):

The code example of your `AppBar`:

```
AppBar(
  leading: IconButton(
    onPressed: Navigator.of(context).pop,
    icon: const Icon(
      Icons.arrow_back,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Instead of `Colors.black` you can use whatever color you want

Answer (score 0):

in the new page, add leading to your appbar:

```
Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
            leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_left, color: Colors.black,),onPressed:(){}),
            ),
```

OR

Apply theme:

```
appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
  iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
```